# Build JSONArray of more than 89 items

Tags: java, android, json

I'm having an issue trying to build a JSONArray in android that has more than 89 items in it. It works fine with 89 items but once i put 90 or more in, i get the error "jsonexception expected : after". I'm still pretty new with the android and java stuff so if theres more error detail i can find that would help, let me know how to do so. I don't think the issue is with the JSON itself, because when i did verify it is valid json from the url itself. I'll post the code below.

```
                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(SERVICE_URL + "/GetResListNoStatus/" + FacID);
            request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            request.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();

            // Read response data into buffer
            char[] buffer = new char[(int)responseEntity.getContentLength()];
            InputStream stream = responseEntity.getContent();
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader.read(buffer);
            stream.close();

                //this line here is where the error is occuring
            JSONArray plates = new JSONArray(new String(buffer));
```

If anyone has any ideas i would really appreciate any help anyone can give. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're only calling read() once on your InputStream.  That will read whatever data is available, which may be all of the request or just a few bytes.  You'll need to call read(buffer) repeatedly, appending what was read to a fixed buffer (you could just just write it into a ByteArrayOutputStream), and stop once read() returns -1.

**Edit**

Try something like this.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.google.com");

        InputStream is = url.openStream();

        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; 

        int count;
        while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            os.write(buffer, 0, count);
        }

        is.close();

        String json = new String(os.toByteArray());

        System.out.println(json);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: so would i put the read in a do while loop until read = -1? is that would you mean?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the error you are getting may be that the whole message isn't being received.

Write out the "new String(buffer)" to logcat.